# Redirect port 4173 to 80

Tags: reactjs, portforwarding, aws-elb

I have a React JS application running on an EC2 Linux VM. The app is accessible only through 4173 port. So, I can access the app using URL:4173. But I want to get rid of this.

How can I use target group and an ELB to redirect port 80 to 4173?

I tried the below:
This is my Target group setting:
Registered the instance on port 4173. Shows as healthy.

[image]

This is the default ELB rule:
ELB created a default rule on HTTP:80 to the Target Group.

[image]

But the application is not reachable. When I try the ELB public DNS name, it says:

> Gateway Timeout Server error - server 35.171.248.21 is unreachable at
> this moment.
>
> Please retry the request or contact your administrator.

[image]

I tried with the port too but it doesn't work.